# How can I reuse an existing web UI project without forking?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, version-control, dependencies

I'm looking for an elegant way to:

1. Reuse an open source web UI project ([Apache Nifi UI](https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/support/nifi-1.9.x/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-web/nifi-web-ui)) in its entirety
2. Apply a bunch of local modifications
3. Maintain 1 and 2 without having to fork the original project

The local modifications are not going to be pushed upstream because the original project owners wouldn't want them.  Modifications include behavioral changes to the UI (aka javascript functionality have changed) and view structure changes (e.g. labels have been removed, face of dialogs have completely been restructured).

Is there a way for me to treat the entire original web UI project as a dependency and extend/override its implementation of various UI components and their actions from another project?

Being able to do this is desirable because the relationship between my changes and the original project becomes a looser coupling.  Forks require the new project owner to actively sync upstream changes and essentially be responsible for any/all implementation issues even if not written by the new author.

If the above is not possible without re-architecting/re-factoring the original project, are there known approaches and techniques that can be applied to the original project to achieve the above?

Comment: no, fork doesn't force anything.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using a git submodule to pin the version, then apply your code modifications as a context-diff-style patch. But you'll have to develop and test basically in a fork, a checked-out copy of NiFi, to produce that patch.

Comment: The *potential* downside of this, is that if you use a submodule, when you run your unit tests (e.g., in Maven), you are going to inherit their unit tests, failing or not, their code coverage numbers, etc.